# how to display/show multiple entities on "home.component.html" in jhipster?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jhipster

I want to display two **entities**(*product*, *recipe*) content on **home** page in jhipster application.
How to achieve this?

**Home.route.ts**

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [MyappSharedModule, RouterModule.forChild([HOME_ROUTE]),
         JhpbackEntityModule],
declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class MyappHomeModule {}
```

After that, in **Home.component.html**
I have added this, but it got error

```
<jhi-product></jhi-product>
<jhi-recipe></jhi-recipe>
```

I can access this entity seperately, at localhost:8080/product and at localhost:8080/recipe
But, at localhost:8080, i want both entities to be displayed

Please, help.
Thanking you

Comment: what error? you should post your code about jhi-product and jhi-recipe too

Comment: error or problem:  'jhi-product' is not a known element:
1. If 'jhi-product' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'jhi-product' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.